# SQL Query involving joins

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

For an SQL assessment I have to carry out a query where I need to list the Car Sales in the past month ordered by Salesman Code.
I have created an SQL statement. However, when I run it, it lists nothing at all except the column names that I have included within the query. The SQL code I have used is below:

```
SELECT CarForSale.SalesmanCode, 
  Salesman.SalesmanName, 
  Customer.CustomerCode, 
  Customer.CustomerName, 
  Customer.CustomerAddress
FROM 
(
  Centre 
  INNER JOIN Customer 
    ON Centre.CentreCode = Customer.CentreCode
) 
INNER JOIN CarForSale 
  ON (Customer.CustomerCode = CarForSale.CustomerCode) 
  AND (Centre.CentreCode = CarForSale.CentreCode), Salesman
WHERE CarForSale.CFSSoldDate BETWEEN CVDATE('01/02/2013') AND  CVDATE('01/03/2013')
ORDER BY Salesman.SalesmanCode;
```

If anyone has any feedback or knows where I am going wrong I would much appreciate some assistance with this problem.

Here is some sample data as requested:

- CFS Table

  ```
   CFSCode CFSMake CFSModel CFSSellingPrice 
   000001 Mercedes  W168         45000             

   CFSSoldDate CentreCode SalesmanCode CustomerCode
   01/03/2013   00000001   0000000001 00000001
  ```
- Salesman Table

  ```
  SalesmanCode SalesmanName SalemanCommThisYear SalesmanStatus CentreCode
  0000000001    Liam Jones       2250         senior        00000001
  ```
- customer table

  ```
  CustomerCode    CustomerName    CustomerAddress   CentreCode    CustomerStatus
  00000001    Gina Smith       1, The Lake,       00000002         good
                               Merthyr Tydfil
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

In your current query, you have some unusual syntax:

```
AND (Centre.CentreCode = CarForSale.CentreCode), Salesman -- what's this
```

I am not sure what the `, Salesman` is supposed to be doing. But if you are trying to `JOIN` on the `Salesman` table, then your query will be:

```
SELECT CarForSale.SalesmanCode, 
  Salesman.SalesmanName, 
  Customer.CustomerCode, 
  Customer.CustomerName, 
  Customer.CustomerAddress
FROM ((Centre 
INNER JOIN Customer 
  ON Centre.CentreCode = Customer.CentreCode) 
INNER JOIN CarForSale 
  ON (Customer.CustomerCode = CarForSale.CustomerCode) 
  AND (Centre.CentreCode = CarForSale.CentreCode)))
INNER JOIN Salesman
  ON CarForSale.SalesmanCode = Salesman.SalesmanCode
WHERE CarForSale.CFSSoldDate BETWEEN #01/02/2013# AND #01/03/2013#
ORDER BY Salesman.SalesmanCode;
```

Also in MS Access, when using dates, they should be surrounded by pound sigs `#`. Your query should be:

```
SELECT CarForSale.SalesmanCode, 
  Salesman.SalesmanName, 
  Customer.CustomerCode, 
  Customer.CustomerName, 
  Customer.CustomerAddress
FROM ((Centre 
INNER JOIN Customer 
  ON Centre.CentreCode = Customer.CentreCode) 
INNER JOIN CarForSale 
  ON (Customer.CustomerCode = CarForSale.CustomerCode) 
  AND (Centre.CentreCode = CarForSale.CentreCode)))
INNER JOIN Salesman
  ON CarForSale.SalesmanCode = Salesman.SalesmanCode
WHERE CarForSale.CFSSoldDate BETWEEN #01/02/2013# AND #01/03/2013#
ORDER BY Salesman.SalesmanCode;
```

Edit #1, I am not sure why you are joining on the `Centre` table since you are not using it for anything.  I just ran the following query in MS Access using your sample data and got results:

```
SELECT CarForSale.SalesmanCode, 
  Salesman.SalesmanName, 
  Customer.CustomerCode, 
  Customer.CustomerName, 
  Customer.CustomerAddress
FROM (Customer 
INNER JOIN CarForSale 
  ON Customer.CustomerCode = CarForSale.CustomerCode)
INNER JOIN Salesman
  ON CarForSale.SalesmanCode = Salesman.SalesmanCode
WHERE CarForSale.CFSSoldDate BETWEEN #01/02/2013# AND #01/03/2013#
ORDER BY Salesman.SalesmanCode;
```

Comment: thank you for your response. When I try to run the SQL code without included Salesman, it prompts me to enter a parameter for the ORDER BY Salesman.Salesman code

Comment: @Alyn Then you will need to `JOIN` to that table. See my edit

Comment: When it displays now though it is just a blank list

Comment: @Alyn How does the `Salesman` table relate to the rest? Is it using the `SalesmanCode`?  If so, are you sure that you have matching data in the tables?

Comment: Sorry, I will add data from the other tables I have

Comment: @Alyn see my edit, I do not know why you are joining on the `Centre` table.  I just put all your sample data into a test ms access database and was able to return results.

Comment: Cheers for that but still I have the problem of no data being listed within the results. I do have Car Sales within the past month so there is no reason why these results shouldnt be showing. I have run the code you have just displayed but got no results :/